# ASP.NET MVC 5 calling controller method from Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to call a controller method from javascript and I seem to be having trouble getting this to execute correctly. I have very little experience with javascript and have followed other examples of how to do this from stackoverflow but I am still having some issues- if anyone can help that'd be fantastic.

Basically what I am trying to do is set a .data tag on a javascript object to the string returned by a method on the controller (this method calls a webservice that runs a SQL Server function). The method needs to be passed one parameter which is used in the function.

The code is below:

**Javascript Code**

```
for (var i = 0; i < stats.length; i++)
{ 
    var stat = stats[i].data('id');
    var color = CallService(stat);
    this.node.fill = color;
}
```

**JQuery Method**

```
    function CallService(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CallService", "NodeController")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: { 'id': id },
        success: function (color) {
            return color;
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error occured');
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller Method**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult CallService(string id)
    {
        var idNum = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        var StationService = new getStationStatus.Service1SoapClient("Service1Soap");
        string color = StationService.getStationStatus(idNum);
        return Json(color, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

the controller is called the NodeController- which is what I am referring to in url: call of ajax.

Basically what is happening is when i run the page, I first get an error saying it cannot set this.node.fill to a null value *THEN* I get the alert that an error occurred- like I said I am pretty inexperienced with javascript so I am honestly not even sure if it is calling the method in the correct order if i get an error on this.node.fill before I receive the error message from JQuery.

Any/all help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Basic async coding error: You cannot return a value from the middle of a callback function (like `success:`) as that happens long after your function has exited. @Igor has some correct suggestions below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If your controller class is `NodeController`, use only "Node" for the controller name in `Url.Action`:

   ```
   url: '@Url.Action("CallService", "Node")',
   ```
2. You cannot synchronously return a value from an asynchronous function. Either pass a callback to `CallService` to be called on success or use jquery promise - http://api.jquery.com/promise/
3. We don't know what `this.node.fill` is or where it is defined. Likely, `this.node` is not defined at the time the assignment is executed.

Comment: Thanks! I needed to use all of your tips, as well as switch the type from a get to a post

Answer (score 2):

You need not to write controller with controller's name

```
@Url.Action("CallService", "Node")
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not fix the problem- i am still seeing the same errors in the same order

Comment: You missed the whole "returning a value from the middle of an async function" problem :)